# Save group layer to a layer file using arcpy (Convert Labels to Annotations)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, labeling, error-000732, group-layer

I am running the "Convert Labels To Annotation" tool in ArcGIS Pro using the Python window. I need to save the output group layer to it's own lyrx file.

According to the [tool documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/cartography/convert-labels-to-annotation.htm), "when working in the Catalog pane, the Python window, or a stand-alone Python script, you can use the Save To Layer File tool to write the output group layer to a layer file."

I attempted this with the following code:

```
for area in os.listdir(outfolder):

    if area == "test":
        # Find the aprx file in each plan
        project = outfolder + "\\" + area + "\\" + area + ".aprx"
        annoLyr = outfolder + "\\" + area + "\\" + area + "_Annos.lyrx"
        print(project)

        print("Opening ArcGIS Project for", area)
        aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(project)

        for map in aprx.listMaps():
            if "_10" in map.name:
                print("Running on", map.name)

                for sc in scales:

                    print("Converting all labels to annotation at scale {}".format(sc))

                    #Convert all labels in entire map to Annotation
                    arcpy.cartography.ConvertLabelsToAnnotation(
                    input_map=map, 
                    conversion_scale=sc, 
                    output_geodatabase=aprx.defaultGeodatabase, 
                    anno_suffix="Anno",
                    extent="DEFAULT",
                    generate_unplaced="GENERATE_UNPLACED",
                    require_symbol_id="NO_REQUIRE_ID",
                    feature_linked="STANDARD",
                    auto_create="AUTO_CREATE",
                    update_on_shape_change="SHAPE_UPDATE",
                    output_group_layer="Annotations",
                    which_layers="ALL_LAYERS",
                    single_layer=None,
                    multiple_feature_classes="FEATURE_CLASS_PER_FEATURE_LAYER",
                    merge_label_classes="NO_MERGE_LABEL_CLASS"
                    )
                arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile("Annotations", annoLyr, "RELATIVE", "CURRENT")
                print("Labels have been converted to annotations.")
```

However, it returns:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset Annotations does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (SaveToLayerFile).
```

I expected just passing the string into it wouldn't work.
The tool is running correctly as it creates all my annotation feature classes, I'm just not sure how to retrieve this group layer. I could list the layers in the map but the group layer hasn't been added to the map. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?